# The finite group of complex numbers

Tags: group-theory

I am currently working through creating a solutions manual to provide students with an overview of group theory. One of the exercises that I have been asked to solve works with the group $\{1, i, -1, -i\}$. This certainly forms a group, which one might call the group of the complex numbers. However, I am unsure if this has a conventional symbol as most other groups have. The problem is that to refer to a group by writing out the entire group every time disrupts the flow of writing. Thus far, I have simply called the group $\zeta$, but if anyone is aware of its actual symbol, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've seen $U_n$ used to denote the cyclic group formed by the $n$th roots of unity.

Comment: This is called the *group of units* of the ring $\Bbb Z[i]\subseteq \Bbb C$. It is isomorphic to $C_4$, generated by $i$, which has order $4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard name you seek is $$\mathbb{Z}[i]^\times$$

Here, $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ normally refers to the [Gaussian integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer), while the superscript $\times$ normally refers to the invertible elements within a ring, also known as the group of units of a ring.  Some people may prefer $$U(\mathbb{Z}[i])$$

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling this the group of complex numbers, this group is ususally referred to as $C_4$, the (up to isomorphism) cyclic group of $4$ elements! The group of complex numbers would be $\mathbb{C}$ with addition, or $\mathbb{C}^*$ with multiplication.

Comment: The problem with your notation is that while they are isomorphic and effectively the same, I also answer questions regarding $C_4$, and construct an isomorphism between the two. This is infact one of the main reasons I need a symbol: I am constructing an isomorphism between $C_4$ and $\zeta$. You are correct though.

Comment: I see, then I would follow the suggestion of Hyperion above, denoting the group by $U_4$, the 4-th roots of unity. You can let your students figure out what $U_5$ and $U_8$ would "look like" / are isomorphic to ...